# Use Enum for user role

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, spring-data-jpa

I have this Entity for users and roles:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test")
public class Test implements Serialazable {
    ....
    @Column(length = 25)
    private String role;
    ..... 
}
```

I want to use this Enum to hold the available types:

```
public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
  ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CLIENT;

  public String getAuthority() {
    return name();
  }

}
```

The questions is how I can use this Enum to insert the selected current role and also to get the value from the database and populate the Enum.

Cna you guide me how to implement this because it's not very clear for me?

Comment: So you're trying to populate an enum at runtime? I doubt that's a great idea, given that enums are supposed to be static.

Comment: In my case I have a fixed types on roles.

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example, you need:

- create a enum class
- create a converter:

  ```
  @Converter(autoApply = true)
  public class RoleConverter implements AttributeConverter<Role, String> {

      @Override
      public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Role role) {
          return role.getRoleName();
      }

      @Override
      public Role convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
          return Role.getFromShortName(dbData);
      }
  }
  ```

The persistence provider will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The most common option to map an enum value to and from its database representation in JPA is to use the @Enumerated annotation. This way, we can instruct a JPA provider to convert an enum to its ordinal or String value.

This post can help you.

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa